# FB.Event.subscribe not registering status:true in Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, google-chrome, authentication, authorization

I would like my my FB app to automatically get information about the user if they are already logged in to FB. In chrome the following code works perfectly and gets the requested information. In Internet Explorer and Firefox, however, the following code only works if I add FB.login(); into the window.fbAsyncInit function. This causes a pop-up to load everytime the page is accessed which I do not want. By using an alert to test my code I have determined that the FB.Event.subscribe function is not even even being called in IE and FF, but works fine in Chrome. Why is this behaving differently in IE and FF and how can I get it to work correctly?

```
 (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));

// Init the SDK upon load
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
      appId      : 'ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : 'Channel Path', // Path to your Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse XFBML
      oauth      : true,
      frictionlessRequests: true
   });

  // listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
      console.log(response);
      if (response.authResponse) {
        // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
         FB.api('/me', function(me){
            if (me.name) {
               userID = me.id;
            }
         });
         document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
      }else {
         // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
         $('#auth-displayname').html('');
         document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

auth.statusChange only gets called when you are already logged into facebook.

I beleave you are testing on chrome, so you are most likely logged in. but when you go to firefox or IE and you are not logged in auth.statusChange nevers gets called

Test by login out of facebook on chrome, and youll see it doesnt work there either.

So you have to make an explicit call to FB.getLoginStatus() to init stuff as soon as the page loads, and listen on statusChange for changes in the future:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // user has auth'd your app and is logged into Facebook
     FB.api('/me', function(me){
        if (me.name) {
           userID = me.id;
        }
     })
    }
 });

// listen for and handle auth.statusChange events
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response){
  if (response.authResponse) {
     document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'block';
  }else {
     // user has not auth'd your app, or is not logged into Facebook
     $('#auth-displayname').html('');
     document.getElementById('auth-loggedout').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('auth-loggedin').style.display = 'none';
  }
```

});